# View or Partial View

Tags: view, razor, partial

How can I find out whether a view (i.e: t.cshtml) is a partial view or a normal view?
Is there a sign or any other thing that differentiates between them?

Answer (score 3):

In Razor you should not talk about views and partial views. They are both templates. And some templates might have layouts (standard views) whereas others not (partials). So you could check whether the Layout property is defined:

```
@string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Layout)
```

If the layout is null or empty you could suppose that this is a partial view. But as I said there's no longer this notion of partial views in Razor. It's just a template without a layout.

Comment: +1 Also, isn't it really just the Controller that defines whether a View rendering is a full View or a Partial View?

Comment: @Shark, not only. You could also set the `Layout` property from inside the template as well.

Comment: Right, but even with the `Layout` property you can still call a `RenderPartial()` on it, no?

Comment: @Shark, yes, absolutely. You can call RenderPartial on any template.